# Why should I care about consistent line endings?

Tags: visual-studio

Sometimes I get this popup asking me if I want to fix the inconsistent line endings in a file I open. I think it's from when I have a file that was generated by some tool that probably uses unix style line endings and then I edit it in VS.

As far as I know there is no harm in having inconsistent line endings. Both the IDE and compiler handles them all the same. So why bother me with this question? Is there some hidden danger I'm not aware of? Or is the Visual Studio team just OCD about this issue?

Comment: Source control systems like Git won't like inconsistent line endings, and generate huge diffs if someone touches the repo and modify line endings mistakenly. Most projects should normalize line endings, before it is too late.

Comment: @LexLi Ah ok, that makes sense. I suppose TFS probably has the same issue?